# java executor with pre-emptable thread queue

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduling

I'm looking for a java thread-pool, that won't run more threads simultaneously than there are cores in the system. This service is normally provided by a ThreadPoolExecutor using a BlockingQueue.

However, if a new thread is scheduled to execute, I want the new thread to pre-empt one of the already running threads, and add the the pre-empted thread (in a suspended state) to a task queue, so it can be resumed as soon as the new thread is finished.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think Java-Threads are not to be used like that, since there is no possibility to temporary stop and then continue a thread, except if you implement such a method at your own. 
But there is no general way to pre-empt a runnable, pause execution and let another thread continue. In fact, there are never more threads *running* than the number of cores in your system.. it a simple law of physics. If you're running more threads than the number of cores in your system, java automatically schedules the available CPUs among the running threads (using pre-emption).

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I know that thread-suspension has been deprecated in java, however there are alternative methods as have been described here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html . I have implemented a similar method to pause my threads. 

My goal is to have the 'new' tasks complete as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make a subclass of ThreadPoolExecutor.

When you setup your ThreadPoolExecutor you want to set the `corePoolSize` and the `maximumPoolSize` to `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` (Look at `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` to see why this works).

Next you want to make sure that your `Queue` also implements `Deque`.  `LinkedBlockingDeque` is an example but you should shop around to see which one will work best for you.  A `Deque` allows you to get stack like LIFO behavior which is exactly what you want.

Since everything (`submit()`, `invokeAll()`) funnels through `execute()` you will want to override this method.  Basically do what you described above:

Check if all threads are running.  If not simply start the new runnable on an available thread.  If all the threads are already running then you need to find the one running the oldest runnable, stop the runnable, re-queue the runnable somewhere (maybe at the beginning?), and then start your new runnable.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of a ThreadPoolExecutor is to avoid all of the expensive actions related to creating and destroying a thread. If you absolutely insist on preempting the running tasks, then you won't get that from the default API.

If you are willing to allow the running tasks to complete and instead only preempt the tasks which have not begun execution, then you can use a BlockingQueue implementation which works like a Stack (LIFO).

You can also have tasks 'preempt' other tasks by using different executors with different thread priorities. Essentially, if the OS supports time-slicing, then the higher priority executor gets the time-slice.

Otherwise, you need a custom implementation which manages execution. You could use a SynchronousQueue and have P worker threads waiting on it. If a client calls execute and SynchronousQueue.offer fails, then you would have to create a special worker Thread which grabs one of the other Threads and flags them to halt before executing and again flags them to resume after executing.